# UWP build and "opens" but will not load when using Xamarin Form and MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, mvvmcross

I have recently begun learning Xamarin development and MvvmCross. I have followe their Xamarin Forms setup on the documentation and got it working for android. I also want to be able to have it work in UWP. I have looked at the "playground app" as shown [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Uwp).

And copied it to my code which I have pushed to [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/parkeradam/XamarinLearning/tree/master/MvvmCrossForms).

The android app runs and renders as expected. The UWP app builds, runs but is stuck on the default Xamarin screen when it runs and makes it no further. 
Is anyone able to advise as I have tried multiple steps found online (adding custom app start, vie presenters etc) but none have worked. 
Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your projects is just right except for one little overlook which makes all the difference :-) .

Go to `App.xaml` and change its contents like this:

```
<local:TipCalcApp
    x:Class="TipCalcMvvmCrossForms.UWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TipCalcMvvmCrossForms.UWP"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

</local:TipCalcApp>
```

The difference is that the original code was using the default `Application` base class whereas here you actually want to use the customized `TipCalcApp` class, which contains all the logic. Once you do this, your app will load without problems. As they always say, the devil is in the details :-) .

Comment: You my friend are a legend! I have been tearing my hair out over this!

Comment: Very glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!